# Get notified about new filename of saved PDF document from Adobe Reader DC

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, acrobat, adobe-reader

Based on data from a SQL database, I dynamically create reports as PDF Report, say costs-2015_01.pdf. This document is automatically saved on a pre-configured (application wide) directory, e.g. C:\reports\costs-2015_01.pdf.

The full path (incl. filename) gets stored in a database table called tblDocuments.

After that, I call acroread.exe with the document path as argument to open the report.

The problematic part is, that the document contains two digital signature fields. If the user signs the document, Reader asks automatically after the signature process for a new file location (Save-as Dialog). Most users are saving the new file under a different name and location instead of overriding the origin file, for example 'C:\My Documents...'.

The problem is: from my calling application, I don't get notified about the new path and can not update the file location in my database document table.
The best solution would be to prevent Reader from asking for a new file location, instead save back the report incl. signature to the origin file.
But that seems impossible. So I'm asking if it is possible to get notified by Reader if the document was saved under a new file name/path.

Users always open PDF files from my application, based on path info stored in tblDocuments. If I can't update the path, users always gets the unsigned - original - pdf document because I'm not aware of the new signed pdf.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try, is to use the `didSave` event (that's one of the Document Actions in the JavaScript tool), where you would submit the path to the database.

How you would do that, depends on your environment.